Edge has a bug with input fields. it immediately displays title, although it should not appear until Mousover
I have several input fields that ask a question. The answer is in the title. This will only be shown at Mousover.
`<input id="text1" type="text" name="text1" autofocus="" title="42"/><br>
<input id="text2" type="text" name="text2"              title="BMW"/><br>
<input id="text3" type="text" name="text3"              title="AUDI"/><br>`

With Tab I can jump to the input fields.
With Edge, the tooltip-title appears immediately.
In Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, the tooltip title only appears on Mousover. That's correct.
Does anyone have an idea where the error is with Edge?
does anyone have a solution?
I have tried many solutions. However, many programming steps are necessary.
I could also omit Edge, but only Edge is allowed in German schools. Chrome, Firefox, Opera are not installed and only the adminstrator can install it.
You can see my page
 https://lern.vingu.de/deutsch/103_der_Kasus_Dativ.php

Could not reproduce on Edge 131.0.2903.112 - is the version of Edge you're using one of the really old EdgeHTML-engine-based browsers?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Note: per MDN doesn't look like there is a requirement that the browser handle title attributes in input tags with tooltips on mouseovers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#title

Microsoft Edge
Version 131.0.2903.112 (Offizielles Build) (64-Bit)

Please, if you are on my site, please use the Enter or Return key, then you can see the Edge error better.
In Chrome, Firefox doesn't fire the tooltip. Only fires when Mousover fires, then it's correct.
